# Sharing on facebook without the native app installed

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sharer

I'm trying to share some stuff on Facebook. following this [guide](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/share#prerequisites) I managed to complete the sharing when you have the native app. However, when I reached this:

Step 4: Using the Feed Dialog as fallback. It says that to be able to use a fallback method, I need to add the code below

```
private void publishFeedDialog() {
    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("name", "Facebook SDK for Android");
    params.putString("caption", "Build great social apps and get more installs.");
    params.putString("description", "The Facebook SDK for Android makes it easier and faster to develop Facebook integrated Android apps.");
    params.putString("link", "https://developers.facebook.com/android");
    params.putString("picture", "https://raw.github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.x-howtos/master/Images/iossdk_logo.png");

    WebDialog feedDialog = (
        new WebDialog.FeedDialogBuilder(getActivity(),
            Session.getActiveSession(),
            params))
        .setOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {

            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values,
                FacebookException error) {
                if (error == null) {
                    // When the story is posted, echo the success
                    // and the post Id.
                    final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
                    if (postId != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                            "Posted story, id: "+postId,
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        // User clicked the Cancel button
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                            "Publish cancelled", 
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } else if (error instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException) {
                    // User clicked the "x" button
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Publish cancelled", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    // Generic, ex: network error
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), 
                        "Error posting story", 
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

        })
        .build();
    feedDialog.show();
}
```

After adding this, I get errors at `getActivity()`, I fix this by using `MyClass.this`.
Then, when I run the app (I directly run this method at startup) my application crashes and I get some error like "attempted to use session that was not open"

Anyone know how to be able to share stuff without the native app installed?

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused because the user has not logged in to Facebook via your app. You will need to implement the Login with Facebook somewhere in your app. Even if the user does not have the native app installed, the Facebook SDK will fall back on the webdialog to request the user to log in. Thus, You will need to check if the session is opened (i.e. user has logged in).

```
Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
boolean isSessionOpen = (session != null && session.isOpened());

if(!isSessionOpen) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Please Login With Facebook First!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will try and test this answer asap. And get back and accept if it worked.